# Encoding wildcarding, stemming, etc in simple search

Tags: wildcard, marklogic

We have a simple search interface which calls the search:search($query-text) function.  Is there a syntax to include control for wildcarding, stemming and case sensitivity within the single text string that the function accepts?  I haven't been able to find anything in the MarkLogic docs.

Answer (score 1):

See the `$options` parameter and the `<term>` and `<term-option>` constraint at https://docs.marklogic.com/search:search . There is a guide at http://developer.marklogic.com/learn/2009-07-search-api-walkthrough
and some details http://developer.marklogic.com/learn/2009-07-search-api-walkthrough#ndbba3437f320a4a4

Comment: Yes, I understand that.  What I am trying to do is to allow the user to enter a term-option tag directly into the #qtext string without having to do backend coding for the interface.  Maybe this is just not possible.

Comment: Your hunch is correct (as is @mblakele). You will need to parse and interpret some syntax yourself to control those options.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any existing syntax for those options, aside from the built-in behavior of turning on wildcards when a term contains '*' or '?' and turning on case-sensitivity when the term contains capital letters.

You could develop a syntax. Implementing it might involve a custom parser along the lines of https://github.com/mblakele/xqysp then feeding the resulting `cts:query` into `search:resolve`.

Comment: Thanks!  That link looks promising.

Comment: Might not be necessary to build an entire syntax parser for this. If you select fixed strings to represent certain options, then you can easily filter those out with more common string manipulation functions..

Answer (score 1):

Piggybacking on Eric Bloch's answer... you can always dynamically construct your  node based on input in the user interface.

For example, I often do this in order to separate the facet selection portion of the query from the text search portion and put the facet selection query in the additional-query element in the options node.